# Underbraces are ruined by mathtools (and maybe unicode-math?). How do I keep both?

Tags: unicode-math, mathtools, underbrace

In writing my thesis (using XeLaTeX) I use multiple math-related packages, all for different reasons. Since introducing unicode-math and mathtools, the underbraces I applied earlier are ruined. I included unicode-math to get proper bold math symbols (I'm using `\symbfit{}`) and I included mathtools for the `\vdotswithin{}` command. One example of a ruined underbrace in my thesis is:

[image: Underbrace in thesis report]

All other underbraces look more or less like this. I created the same equation in a MWE. I realise the MWE could be even more minimal by writing a more minimal equation, but I think it is minimal and clear enough to illustrate the problem and in this way, the equation is the same as in my thesis. I left in the physics package and the `\pqty{}` command to verify that this is not the cause of my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\bi}[1]{\symbfit{#1}}

\begin{document}
$\underbrace{q\pqty{\bi{x}}}_{\text{R-density}}\qquad\qquad\underbrace{p\qty(\bi{x},\bi{y})}_{\text{G-density}} = \underbrace{p\pqty{\bi{y}|\bi{x}}}_{\text{likelihood}}\underbrace{p\pqty{\bi{x}}}_{\text{prior}}$
\end{document}
```

In both the thesis and the MWE, I get these warnings:

> Using \overbracket and \underbracket from(unicode-math) `mathtools'
> package.
>
> I'm going to overwrite the following commands(unicode-math) from the
> `mathtools' package:(unicode-math)(unicode-math) \dblcolon, \coloneqq,
> \Coloneqq, \eqqcolon.

When I don't include the mathtools package, I don't get the warning. In the MWE, the underbraces look fine in both cases, despite the warning:

[image: Underbraces in MWE]

I've also excluded mathtools in my thesis, which gives me back the underbraces. However, I then cannot use `\vdotswithin{}` in an entirely different part of my thesis. Is there a solution that allows me to use the underbraces, bold math from unicode-math and `\vdotswithin{}` from mathtools? Or another solution that gives me these (or similar results)?

EDIT: After some comments I realised my MWE doesn't use the .cls file that my thesis report does. When I change the documentclass in the MWE, I can reproduce the problem (like in the first image). Not including the mathtools package then again `solves' the problem. The .cls for my thesis uses the Cambria font for math.. I don't know if the font is the problem, since the underbraces work fine without the mathtools package.

Comment: What do you mean "despite the warning"? The warning is about `\underbracket`s, which has nothing to do with `\underbrace`s. As you say, the MWE you posted compiles fine. Can you post some code which actually shows the problem?

Comment: In the original screenshot you're using a font which differs from Computer Modern (or Latin Modern). It looks like Cambria Math. May be the problem is with its usage?

Comment: Exactly which latex installation are you using? On TeXLive 2020 I get the expected underbrace no matter which order `mathtools` and `unicode-math` are loaded in'

Comment: @campa Some things I hadn't noticed yet, like the difference between `\underbracket` and `\underbrace`. I only use `\underbrace`, and I have the problem shown. Not sure how it is related to `\underbracket` from the warning.

Comment: @Sergei Golovan I had not thought of font yet, sharp! For my thesis I use a .cls file from my university which implements different fonts. Possibly this is part of the problem. It is clear though, even in my thesis and not the MWE, that I get proper underbraces when I exclude the mathtools package. So I'm not sure the font is the problem? The underbraces can be created using this font just fine without mathtools

Comment: @daleif Not sure what exactly I should answer, but I work on Windows 10, using MikTeX and Texmaker.

Comment: Is the cls from your university even compatible with xelatex and `unicode-math`?

Comment: @daleif It is meant to be used with xelatex, to adhere to the house style. If I use pdflatex or latex or pslatex, it will use different fonts. When using xelatex, it uses cambria for math. I have no idea about unicode-math, but this seems to work fine (I get the output I want).

Comment: Seems indeed the .cls has something to do with my problem. I changed the MWE to use that .cls instead of article and then I have my problem in the MWE. Excluding mathtools then again `solves' the problem. I hadn't thought of using the .cls in my MWE yet, so thanks for pointing me there. I will edit the question. I have no idea now though, how to solve the problem :( (PS the .cls file can be found here: https://www.tudelft.nl/huisstijl/downloads/ -> Latex Templates -> Rapport)

Comment: First of, AFAIK `mathtools` should be loaded before `unicode-math`. After that is done add `\let\normalunderbrace=\underbrace` before `mathtools` and  `\let\underbrace=\normalunderbrace` after. Then it seems to work.

Comment: @daleif You're awesome, it works like a charm! If you add this as an answer I'll be happy to accept it :)